# Pointer to pointer interconversion

Tags: c, pointers

Is it safe to convert an `int pointer` to `void pointer` and then back to `int pointer`?

```
main()
{
    ...
    int *a = malloc(sizeof(int));
    ...
    *a=10;
    func(a);
    ...
}

void func(void *v)
{
    int x=*(int *)v;
    ...
}
```

Is this a valid way of getting the integer value back in the function?

Comment: And what exactly is the motivation for writing code like this?

Comment: @NullUserException, passing a persistent value to a thread runner function. See pthread_create for more info.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes, it is safe. The Standard says so (6.3.2.3/1)

> A pointer to void may be converted to or from a pointer to any
>   incomplete or object type. A pointer to any incomplete or object
>   type may be converted to a pointer to void and back again;
>   the result shall compare equal to the original pointer.

Answer (score 5):

It is "safe" insofar as the pointer resulting from the int => void => int conversion will be the same as the original pointer.

It is not "safe" insofar as it's easy to get wrong and you have to be careful (that said, this type of code is often necessary in C, since `void*` is often used as a form of generalization).